# How can I have IDA replace an offset with the label of the function the offset points to?

Tags: ida

I keep seeing the same pattern in the code I'm analyzing. A call instruction is using a label "off_" which is just a pointer to the real address of the call (in this case: GetWindowTextW).  It would be much more convenient for me to see call GetWindowTextW (or user32_GetWindowTextW).  This much be an option I can set somewhere or a way to reanalyze the application... but I can't seem to find it.  How can I achieve this?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How do you know that the dword at `off_10010AD8` is constant? For all IDA knows, it might get modified dynamically, so the same call doesn't really always call `GetWindowTextW`. If you know the value is constant, you can rename the label, or write an idc/idapython script to search for these pointers and rename them for you.

Comment: You raise a really great point.  I found that when I renamed off_10010AD8 to GetWindowTextW (well, first it said that name exists and renamed it to GetWindowTextW_0) it brough all of the parameter names to the calling function, which is really what I was looking for.

I suppose a script to hunt out these types of patterns might be my best bet.  I haven't had experience with writing scripts for IDA yet.